# Filtering in gapminder

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a table from the dslabs gapminder data that contains only country = "United States" or "Vietnam", and between the years 1960 and 2010. Theoretically there should be at least 100 rows, but I keep ending up with a dataframe that contains only 58 rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
data(gapminder)
gapminder %>% filter(., year == c(1960:2010), country == c("Vietnam"| "United States"))
```

Comment: I guess you need `country %in% c("Vietnam", "United States")`

Comment: Try: `gapminder %>% filter( year >=  1960, year <= 2010, country %in% c("Vietnam", "United States"))`

Comment: This worked too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gapminder %>% 
    dplyr::filter(year %in% c(1960:2010)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(country %in% c("Vietnam","United States"))
```